# apple-touch-icon displaying shrunken on Safari Bookmark

Tags: html, progressive-web-apps, favicon, apple-touch-icon

I have the following line in `index.html` that declares my `apple-touch-icon` file.

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/images/logo192.png"/>
```

When I attempt to add the website as a bookmark in Safari (16.3, macOS Ventura 13.2), the icon displays shrunken, when ideally it should fill the rounded-rectangle container. See my icon below, and see for example Stripe's:

[image: apple-touch-icon]

[image: Stripe's apple-touch-icon]

The image I'm using is a `.png` sized 192 x 192. Has anyone encountered this before and managed to solve it?

Comment: I have the same issue. Updating in the hope it fixes it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue (bug) has been resolved in Safari 16.4 (macOS) and iOS 16.4.

Comment: That does not fix it.